# How to find the device model my application is running on in C#?

Tags: c#, tablet

I am trying to develop a feature into an application which requires the device mode # on which the application is running. This is a windows application intended to run on various models of tablets.

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
Environment.MachineName;
```

Above two return the name of the device but I need the model number of the device, is there a way to get this information?

Comment: maby this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7164387/1849444

Comment: Why query device info and not capabilities?

Comment: We need this for retrieving the NMEA coordinates on any device and the serial port is not always the same one used on different tablets for gps. But, this port will be the same for a particular model of a device.

Comment: spent all morning yet no way out of it.. this should have been simple. why can i not find any information on this at all?